# Unable to execute SQL system procedure using Python script

Tags: python, c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting an error when trying to execute SQL Server system procedures such as `sp_addLinkedServer` and `sp_dropserver` etc from python script

```
USE [master]

EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'DS', @droplogins='bs'
```

Error:

> (15002, b"The procedure 'sys.sp_dropserver' cannot be executed within a transaction.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

Comment: The error seems pretty clear - you can't run that stored procedure in a transaction. Is it possible you're using [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#autocommit) with `connection.autocommit = True`?

Comment: i am using pymssql library for connecting to database. Any property available in pymssql to disable transaction?